# user to see Terms and conditions screen at password change

Tags: powershell

The company I am working for would like a splash screen that I did to pop up when ever a user changes password (90 day rule at present), this is mainly due to a external requirement.

One of the snags I have is that the system has no email to show me that a user is expiring, I am looking at a couple of things

1. A log output of expired accounts and locked accounts, ignoring accounts not logged on disabled accounts system etc.
2. On the 90 day policy a splash screen pops up with the t$c with an accept or decline window (they see this when they first turn the PC and pops up just before the logon box on basically saying by accepting you agree to have read blah and blah)

I do not know how to get either this to run as one script or have two separate scripts,

Any input greatly appreciated

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory # Required for PowerShell 2.0 only

$a = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-89)

# The following line will build the variable based upon the noted criteria
$b = Get-ADUser `
    -Property Name, SamAccountName, PasswordLastSet, CannotChangePassword, PasswordNeverExpires `
    -Filter { (PasswordLastSet -lt $a) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) } |
    Where-Object { $_.CannotChangePassword -eq $false }

# The following line will display/export the data logging the accounts to be changed
# please note the Out-File path and change to suit your needs.
$b | Format-Table Name, PasswordLastSet, CannotChangePassword, PasswordNeverExpires -AutoSize |
    Out-File -FilePath "C:\passwordchanges.txt"

# The following line will actually flag the accounts to require a password change
# (after -WhatIf is removed)
$b.SamAccountName | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to add some code you have written, so we can help you fix it. Do you know how to list the disabled/locked/expired accounts ? Do you know how to retrieve the last password change date ? (I know about PowerShell only)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the prompt response so the code

Comment: It's still not clear what the problem is here. Is the script not working as expected? If so, what did you expect, and what happened?

Comment: Hi Thanks part of the problem I have is I can not test run the script correctly due to limitations on the system so I am shooting blind, the second is I am not a powershell/script type person. I am trying to put some thing basic together to show it can be done before  getting on the system . this machine for example is not allowed on the prod network it is stand alone ,   I am not too sure if I am looking at this the right way, as in I want to know when a user changes there password but I want then to accept a T&C's screen this will be logged

Comment: `$a` should be `$limitDate` and `$b` should be `$userList`, IMHO